# Reaction rate of Mg with aryl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, halides, grignard-reagent

I have been thinking of the rate of reaction of aryl bromide and aryl chloride with  $\ce{Mg}$ to form Grignard.

When considering the electronegativities the carbon in aryl chloride is more positively polarized. But when considering the bond energies carbon chlorine bond is stronger.

I want to know which factor is more significant when we consider the reaction rates of aryl chloride and aryl bromide with $\ce{Mg}$ to form Grignard.

Comment: Bond energy is key.  Magnesium is easily electropositive enough to barrel its way in unless facing a high activatiin energy.

Comment: So that means aryl bromide forms grignard faster than aryl chloride right?

Comment: On target.  In fact bromides generally react faster than chlorides.